Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that there exists $c \in [-1, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c^5$.

Suppose that the function $f : [-1, 1] \rightarrow [-1, 1]$ is continuous. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that there exists $c \in [-1, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c^5$.

From practise, I understand that this is the correct solution (and I have checked this):
If $f(-1) = -1$ then we choose $c = -1$ and there is nothing else to prove.
Similarly, if $f(1) = 1$ then we choose $c = 1$.
So suppose that $f(-1) \neq -1$ and $f(1) \neq 1$.
Since $f(x) \in [-1, 1]$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$, then we must have that $f(-1) > -1$ and $f(1) < 1$.
We now define a new function $g : [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x^5 - f(x)$.
Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$, polynomials are continuous, and sums of continuous functions are continuous, then the function $g$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$.
Furthermore, from the conditions $f(-1) > -1$ and $f(1) < 1$, we have that $g(-1) = -1 - f(-1) < 0$ and $g(1) = 1 - f(1) > 0$ so that $g(-1) < 0 < g(1)$.
Hence, applying the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $g$ on the interval $[-1, 1]$, we conclude that there exists $c \in (-1, 1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$; i.e. such that $f(c) = c^5$.
My confusion:
What I don't understand is, it is evident to me that $f(-1)=(-1)^5=-1$ which is indeed -1 and $f(1)=1^5=1$ which is indeed 1, so why do we have to continue and suppose that this isn't true when it clearly is? For this topic I know what to answer but I want to have an understanding of why I am saying this.
Additionally, why do we make a new function $g(z)$? What is it's significance? Do we construct $g(x)$ in this way every time?
Please note that I have spent time researching this, but I am still confused hence why I have written this.
Thank you!

$f(\pm1)$ need not be $+1$ or $-1$. $f(-1) = -1/2$ is a possibility, for example.

See, this is where I am confused. I thought the function itself is $f(c)=c^5$ hence why I thought $f(-1)=(-1)^5=-1$. When I say it is evident, I do not mean I am correct sorry I do not know how to word it. I mean to say this is how I see it, can someone please explain my error thank you

Thank you for your comment! I am wondering why this is the case, since they defined $f$ as $f(c)=c^5$, sorry it may be a silly question

Who told you that $f(-1)=(-1)^5$.

In the question, it says such that $f(c)=c^5$. I presume that I am misinterpreting this?

You are asked to use the hypotheses to prove the existence of one value $c \in [-1,+1]$ such that $f(c)=c^5$. You certainly are not free to assume that this conclusion (which are trying to prove) is true for all values.

It's exists a $c$, not for all $c$ - common beginner mistake.

Ohh I understand now! We are saying that we are simply looking for a value, c, between -1 and 1, that when plugged into a certain function, results in $c^5$! Thank you everyone for your helpful explanations :)

"It is evident to me that $f(-1)=(-1)^5=-1$... and $f(1)=1^5=1$" How is this evident to you? This need not be true, and in fact isn't even
"usually" true. Consider the function $f(x):=0$ or $f(x):= -x/2+1/3$ or many others. I don't know why you think that $f(-1)$ must equal $-1$ for any function $f$.
You are not being given that $f(c)=c^5$ for all $c$ but instead being asked to prove that there is even one value where this is the case. You cannot assume the consequent, much less a stronger statement than the consequent.
Your other question. Obviously, the decision to give the function $g$ a name is arbitrary. But naming things lets us talk about them. It is easier to consider the function $g$ (and thus apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to it) if we have named it, than if we were just considering $x \mapsto x^5-f(x)$.
Does this answer your questions?

Yes, it does thank you very much!

The idea is that we are looking for a $c$ that satisfies $f(c) = c^5$. Apriori we do not know the functional form of $f$, in particular it is not defined by $f(x) = x^5$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.
If our function $f$ happens to satisfy $f(1) = 1$ then we have found such a $c$, ie. take $c = 1$. Similarly, if $f(-1) = -1$ we can take $c = -1$. For instance, if $f(x) = x$ then these conditions are satisfied.
But it's possible that $f$ does not satisfy these conditions. For example, it might be the case that $f$ is defined by $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Then clearly
$$f(x) = 0 \implies f(1) \neq 1$$
$$f(x) = 0 \implies f(-1) \neq -1$$
If $f(-1) \neq -1$ and $f(1) \neq 1$ then we still need to prove such a $c$ exists.

The OP was confused about why 'there exists' doesn't mean $f(c):=c\mapsto c^5$. I can't understand how one would equate those two concepts, but hopefully he replies somewhere that he understands the proof now.

I understand, thank you it is late and I am very tired sorry!

You know more than that $f$ is that it is continuous with bounded domain and range. For example, the domain of $f$ is connected, which is vital to the theorem actually working on the domain. This answer is wrong until that part has been edited, or rather it leaves out an important detail where there exists an $f$ matching your description but now the statement is false (consider the map $x \mapsto x^3$ on $X:=[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$. There does not exist a $c$ for which $f(c)=c^5$, yet $X$ is bounded by $[-1,+1]$.

@Tay congratulations, you upvoted the only incorrect answer.. See my comment..

I don't think the exact assumptions on $f$ were the source of the confusion, but rather that $f$ was an unspecified function and not defined by $f(x) = x^5$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. But I will update my comment to be more precise.

@msantama yes you are correct, this was the source of my confusion, hence why I upvoted your comment as it made the most sense to me :)

@Snared thank you for your explanation too.

@Tay No problem - I left the first answer but I'm glad that somebody rewording the same thing (though in an incorrect way that they later had to be told to fix) was able to get you to understanding. Whatever it takes to get you there - Hope you have a good rest of your course! Best of luck.

$f(\pm1)$ need not be $+1$ or $-1$. $f(-1) = -1/2$ is a possibility, for example. $f$ is any continuous function $[-1,+1] \to [-1,+1] $, as stated in your problem.
It's just that if it is plus or minus one on the matching boundary, then you're done, since $f(c)=c^{\text{ odd positive integer}}$.
All that's left is the case where $f(-1)=a$ with $a>-1$ and $f(1)=b$ with $b<1$, which is the application of intermediate value theorem which you did.

Perfect, thank you!

@Luke Don't forget kindly to select a best answer if one answered your question!
